# How to detect if text is rotated 180 degrees or flipped upside down

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am working on a text recognition project. There is a chance the text is rotated 180 degrees. I have tried tesseract-ocr on terminal, but no luck. Is there any way to detect it and correct it? An example of the text is shown below.

[image]

```
tesseract input.png output
```

Comment: run your ocr on multiple rotated versions of the image

Comment: Just train a binary classifier, it should be easy enough.

Comment: @alec_djinn, binary classifier? This is interesting. Can you tell me more details?

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@ipaar3/how-i-built-a-convolutional-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-from-scratch-f852c34e1c95  in your case your training data will be a bunch of images with both orientations. Once trained, you can use the classifier on the fly to preprocess your data.

Comment: There are a few classifiers for image orientation already available on github https://github.com/pulkitmaloo/Image-Orientation-Classification  just retrain them with your type of images and it is done.

Comment: tesseract offers orientation detection. See segmentation options

Answer (score 4):

**tesseract input.png - --psm 0 -c min_characters_to_try=10**

```
Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Page number: 0
Orientation in degrees: 180
Rotate: 180
Orientation confidence: 0.74
Script: Latin
Script confidence: 1.67
```

Comment: What does it mean "short text"? It works on provided input image.

Comment: short text means there is only single letter, number or just one word. I have tried these scenarios in tesseract, but no luck

Comment: You can use variable `min_characters_to_try` to specify minimum characters to try during OSD. Of couse less characters will lead to lower confidence

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach to detect if text is rotated 180 degrees is to use the observation that text tends to be skewed towards the bottom. Here's the strategy:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Gaussian blur
- Threshold image
- Find the top/bottom half ROIs of thresholded image
- Count non-zero array elements for each half

Threshold image

[image]

Find ROIs of top and bottom half

[image]

[image]

Next we split the top/bottom sections

[image]

With each half we count non-zero array elements using [`cv2.countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero). We get this

```
('top', 4035)
('bottom', 3389)
```

By comparing the values between the two halves, *if the top half has more pixels than the bottom half, it is upside down by 180 degrees.* *If it has less, it is correctly oriented.*

Now that we have detected if it is upside down, we can rotate it using this function

```
def rotate(image, angle):
    # Obtain the dimensions of the image
    (height, width) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (width / 2, height / 2)

    # Grab the rotation components of the matrix
    matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(matrix[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(matrix[0, 1])

    # Find the new bounding dimensions of the image
    new_width = int((height * sin) + (width * cos))
    new_height = int((height * cos) + (width * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    matrix[0, 2] += (new_width / 2) - cX
    matrix[1, 2] += (new_height / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, matrix, (new_width, new_height))
```

Rotating the image

```
rotated = rotate(original_image, 180)
cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)
```

which gives us the correct result

[image]

This is the pixel result if the image was correctly oriented

```
('top', 3209)
('bottom', 4206)
```

Full code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def rotate(image, angle):
    # Obtain the dimensions of the image
    (height, width) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (width / 2, height / 2)

    # Grab the rotation components of the matrix
    matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(matrix[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(matrix[0, 1])

    # Find the new bounding dimensions of the image
    new_width = int((height * sin) + (width * cos))
    new_height = int((height * cos) + (width * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    matrix[0, 2] += (new_width / 2) - cX
    matrix[1, 2] += (new_height / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, matrix, (new_width, new_height))

image = cv2.imread("1.PNG")
original_image = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

x, y, w, h = 0, 0, image.shape[1], image.shape[0]

top_half = ((x,y), (x+w, y+h/2))
bottom_half = ((x,y+h/2), (x+w, y+h))

top_x1,top_y1 = top_half[0]
top_x2,top_y2 = top_half[1]
bottom_x1,bottom_y1 = bottom_half[0]
bottom_x2,bottom_y2 = bottom_half[1]

# Split into top/bottom ROIs
top_image = thresh[top_y1:top_y2, top_x1:top_x2]
bottom_image = thresh[bottom_y1:bottom_y2, bottom_x1:bottom_x2]

cv2.imshow("top_image", top_image)
cv2.imshow("bottom_image", bottom_image)

# Count non-zero array elements
top_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(top_image)
bottom_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(bottom_image)

print('top', top_pixels)
print('bottom', bottom_pixels)

# Rotate if upside down
if top_pixels > bottom_pixels:
    rotated = rotate(original_image, 180)
    cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Interesting Idea, but it probably won't work with all-caps text.

Comment: Thanks @nathancy. Great idea, but method is not robust.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of liked the `pytessaract` solution.

```py
import cv2 
import pytesseract
from scipy.ndimage import rotate as Rotate 

def float_convertor(x):
    if x.isdigit():
        out= float(x)
    else:
        out= x
    return out 

def tesseract_find_rotatation(img: str):
    img = cv2.imread(img) if isinstance(img, str) else img
    k = pytesseract.image_to_osd(img)
    out = {i.split(":")[0]: float_convertor(i.split(":")[-1].strip()) for i in k.rstrip().split("\n")}
    img_rotated = Rotate(img, 360-out["Rotate"])
    return img_rotated, out
```

### usage

```py
img_loc = ""
img_rotated, out = tessaract_find_rotation(img_loc)
```

Comment: `k = pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, output_type='dict')` would shorten your code