# Detect PDF file upside down (180 degree angle)

Tags: python

I have various pdf files (which contain both text and tables) from which I subsequently have to recognize the text. The problem is that the file can be flat, that is, at an angle of 0 degrees, or it can be upside down, that is, at an angle of 180 degrees.

Tell me how can I recognize that the file is upside down and make it readable.

That is, here is an example, I received the file (photo below)

[image]

I would like the program to define it as inverted and bring it to a readable form (as in the figure below)

[image]

Comment: I would be assuming that these are actually images. If they are images, you could use a OCR extractor and check confidence in both orientations. Or you could simply train a simple neural net that would classify the pages as flipped or unflipped. Many approaches with varying confidence. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139251/how-to-detect-if-text-is-rotated-180-degrees-or-flipped-upside-down

Answer (score 0):

you can use pypdf2

```
import PyPDF2

def detect_page_rotation(input_path):
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

        for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            rotation = page.get('/Rotate', 0)
            print(f"Page {page_num + 1} rotation: {rotation} degrees")

input_pdf = 'path/to/input.pdf'  

detect_page_rotation(input_pdf)
```

this is the responsible of detecting the page orientation

```
    rotation = page.get('/Rotate', 0)
```

it retrieve the orientation of each page in the pdf The default rotation is 0 degrees if the page does not have a rotation property it will change it i hope this can help

also dont forget to install PyPDF2

```
pip install PyPDF2
```